# Symfony - Composer update - need to user older dependencies (PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.3)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Basically I have an issue - we have a Symfony site built on PHP 5.4 but our server runs PHP 5.3 (yeah - it's old and has over 200 sites on it so I'm not wanting to upgrade just in case it breaks older sites!)

We know the issue is with Doctrine (shorthand array syntax) - and it's possible to update the files manually and use older array syntax.

But I should be able to do via Composer - but I'm unsure on which command to use.

I know it'll probably be something really simple.  I thought I'd ask first as I might save me time having to restore a backup if it goes wrong!

UPDATE:

Tried `composer install`

> Problem 1
>       - doctrine/orm v2.5.0 requires php >=5.4 -> your PHP version (5.3.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - doctrine/orm v2.5.0 requires php >=5.4 -> your PHP version (5.3.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Installation request for doctrine/orm v2.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.0].

Tried `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

> Nothing to install or update

Tried `composer update`

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule.php on line 51

Wasn't expecting that response - maybe there's a server config issue. Shame it did look like it was doing something!

Comment: What do you mean with command? Just open your composer.json and change the required php version to 5.3... something. You just have to check if all your required bundles support these versions. i.e. doctrine Bundle needs "php": ">=5.3.9",

Comment: ok -  so just running composer update will downgrade the doctrine to work on 5.3.    currently the line in composer is  "php": ">=5.3.3",

Comment: The problem is the other dependencies which has the php requirement, that's why ignore-platform-reqs should work!

Comment: What I would do is to create a new Symfony project under 5.3 with: composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project "2.7.*" Then use the resulting composer.json as my starting point.  And of course set your development machines back to 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Using `--ignore-platform-reqs` will not help you, it will make things worse. As I take it from your question, you have an old 5.4 PHP in your development, and an even older 5.3 on your production machine.

The task I see is how to update dependencies for the production PHP using the development PHP.

Fortunately you can tell Composer to assume a different version of PHP instead if the PHP it is currently running on.

You can configure it globally for any Composer call you do on a certain machine, or you can configure it for a single project. Your decision depends on what you expect to do with the development machine, i.e. if you have to support yet another project with different requirements or not.

`composer config -g platform.php 5.3.16` would be the global configuration, and the local configuration would omit the `-g`.

The effect of the global configuration is that Composer will create or add to the file `~/.composer/config.json` a section with the exact PHP version number. Do use the exact full and correct version! PHP 5.3 had some important bugfixes during its lifetime, and the patch level matters, because later PHP versions don't require certain workarounds in PHP code. You should avoid running software without the workarounds on a still broken version.

Running the command in the local version will add the to-be-assumed PHP version to the projects `composer.json` file.

After the platform is added, you just run `composer update` and should see packages being installed that are compatible with the given PHP 5.3 version.

During production deployment, you'd simply run `composer install --no-dev` without any additional effort.

Comment: Thanks for you input - i'll look into this +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

In most server environments it should be possible to install more than one PHP version at a time and use a specific version only for a specific folder/site (e.g. by activating it via htaccess). So your 200 sites can use the old version as standard and your new site can use the new PHP version. I did this on one of my servers too and this is a nice solution for me that I don't have to upgrade all code at once.

Later when all sites are updated (the time comes when you will need to update them due to missing security updates of older PHP versions) then you can set a newer version as default PHP version and omit the old ones.